# Wordpress featured image not working on homepage

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I have tried and researched but can't find a solution to this. Basically I'm trying to display a particular post (post_id 1) on the homepage with its featured image.

The title and excerpt work fine, but the featured image does not.

```
<?php
$post_id = 1;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo "<h2>" . $title . "</h2>";
echo "<p>" . $queried_post->post_excerpt . "</p>";
the_post_thumbnail();
?>
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

with:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
```

Comment: Thanks. Pretty obvious when I think about it :-)